# Asp.Net Core - Bind a model's property to a different named value

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, model-binding

I have the following situation.
I have implemented OData, and I'm using $filter like this: `$filter=Name eq 'test.txt'`

What I want to do is, use aliases for the fileds in files. For example i want the query `$filter=name eq 'test.txt'` to be also valid. 
Currently when I try this, Im getting this error: `Could not find a property named 'name' on type 'My.App.DataAccess.Model.File`

**Model**

```
public class File 
{
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFiles(,
[FromQuery]ODataQueryParameters parameters)
{
    var modelManager = (IODataModelManger)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IODataModelManger));
    var model = modelManager.GetModel(nameof(My.App));
    var queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(File), null);
    var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, HttpContext.Request, Provider);

    var result = await FileService.GetFilesM(queryOptions);

    return Json(result);
}
```

I've found this interesting page: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/bind-a-model-property-to-a-different-named-query-string-field.html , but I just couldn't adapt this to my needs, its to old.

Does anyone know how to bind a model property to a different named query string field?